# How to Save Jmeter Reponse Data (JSON type data) in CSV format

Tags: json, automation, jmeter

i am hitting REST API and the output comes in json in Response Data .i want to save that data automatically in CSV format .

```
{  
  "suggestedLocations":[  
    {  
      "distance":521,
      "eLoc":"JEU3UB",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.544811,
      "entryLongitude":77.267884,
      "keywords":[  
        "PRKWPM"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.544832,
      "longitude":77.2675620000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":1,
      "placeAddress":"Shyam Nagar,New Delhi,Delhi",
      "placeName":"Banarsidas Chandiwala Institute of Medical Science Hospital Parking",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":558,
      "eLoc":"4E2C94",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.544919,
      "entryLongitude":77.267829,
      "keywords":[  
        "COMGAT"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.5444890000001,
      "longitude":77.2676670000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":2,
      "placeAddress":"Sri Maa Anandamayi Ashram Marg,Shyam Nagar,New Delhi,Delhi",
      "placeName":"Banarsidas Chandiwala Hospital Gate No 2",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":607,
      "eLoc":"JU2KU8",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.54492,
      "entryLongitude":77.267829,
      "keywords":[  
        "HLTHSP"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"+911149020301",
      "latitude":28.5441200000001,
      "longitude":77.266806,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":3,
      "placeAddress":"Kalkaji Address Chandiwala Estate, Maa Anandmai Ashram Marg, Kalkaji",
      "placeName":"Banarsidas Chandiwala Institute of Medical Science Hospital",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":876,
      "eLoc":"7YURV9",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.557416,
      "entryLongitude":77.266518,
      "keywords":[  
        "SHPCOM"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.5572960000001,
      "longitude":77.2663660000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":4,
      "placeAddress":"Max House 1, Dr Jha Marg, Okhla",
      "placeName":"ALPS Hospital Ltd",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":1040,
      "eLoc":"258S85",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.54495,
      "entryLongitude":77.258571,
      "keywords":[  
        "HLTHSP"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.5450080000001,
      "longitude":77.2584680000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":5,
      "placeAddress":"D Block, Kalkaji Extension",
      "placeName":"Kalkaji Hospital",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":1049,
      "eLoc":"11A8D2",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.558332,
      "entryLongitude":77.271274,
      "keywords":[  
        "HLTHSP"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.5583580000001,
      "longitude":77.2715460000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":6,
      "placeAddress":"Zakir Bagh Apartment,Ishwar Nagar,New Delhi,Delhi",
      "placeName":"Government Hospital",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":1061,
      "eLoc":"T1D2A4",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.543885,
      "entryLongitude":77.259128,
      "keywords":[  
        "HLTHSP"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"+911126439867, +911126437885, +911126419895",
      "latitude":28.543983,
      "longitude":77.2589550000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":7,
      "placeAddress":"DD 15, Near Main Post office, Kalkaji",
      "placeName":"Shubham Hospital",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":1082,
      "eLoc":"A20AL1",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.544864,
      "entryLongitude":77.25828,
      "keywords":[  
        "HLTHSP"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.544673,
      "longitude":77.2581950000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":8,
      "placeAddress":"Thana Road, Near Chandra Gas Agency",
      "placeName":"Irene Hospital",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":1305,
      "eLoc":"6X0RTW",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.547451,
      "entryLongitude":77.254602,
      "keywords":[  
        "HLTHSP"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.547291,
      "longitude":77.254686,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":9,
      "placeAddress":"C 30-31, Nehru Enclave, Kalkaji Road, Block G, Near HDFC Bank ATM",
      "placeName":"Triton Hospital",
      "type":"POI"
    },
    {  
      "distance":1339,
      "eLoc":"E19PBI",
      "email":"",
      "entryLatitude":28.56004,
      "entryLongitude":77.274484,
      "keywords":[  
        "PRKMLT"
      ],
      "landlineNo":"",
      "latitude":28.56003,
      "longitude":77.2744980000001,
      "mobileNo":"",
      "orderIndex":10,
      "placeAddress":"Escort Area,Masihgarh,New Delhi,Delhi",
      "placeName":"Escort Hospital Multilevel Parking",
      "type":"POI"
    }
  ],
  "explanation":{  
    "refLocation":"28.549513,77.267809",
    "keyword":"hospital"
  }
}
```

like this is my json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save all your JSON data by doing following steps:

1. First copy your reportgenerator.properties file.
2. Now paste that file in the user.properties folder
3. Save both the files.
4. Now restart the jmeter and run any test.
5. Now you will see the json file automatically saving on your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

I can think only of the following approach:

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=response
   jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=|
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which response data you would like to save and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('response', org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.normalizeSpace(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))
   ```
3. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```
4. Once your test finishes you will see `result.csv` file containing "normal" JMeter metrics AND response data as the last column called `response`

   [image: JMeter Response Data as CSV]

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score -1):

You can use plugin jsonpathextractor for storing the json resopnse data.here is below link for process. please review it and let me know any problem.

https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/

To Write the CSV file use below video will help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUtBQNd5YxE